# Inline Box Highlighting in Jekyll w/ Example Target

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, inline, jekyll

I'm trying to achieve a specific code highlighting effect. For an example, take a look at the Jekyll guide http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#markdown-options. This site shows a lot of inline text boxed up in pretty code highlighting formatting. I've got my site displaying Pygments highlighting, but I can't for the life of me figure out how the Jekyll site is doing it. Here is the source for the page linked above:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/jekyll/master/site/_docs/usage.md

This file uses '' apostrophes to mark the text that ends up formatted the way I want. I can't fine documentation anywhere of what system is coming in and performing this formatting. Can anybody shed light on the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I missed that the apostrophe-like characters in the post were actually backticks (`) and not apostrophes ('). Using these characters permits highlighting using normal markdown rules.